# Aws Api Gateway Request with .Net 4.0 getting 403

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, request, aws-api-gateway, httpclient

I have an api gateway service in AWS. I want to create request to the this service.

This is my method which calls the request;

```
public List<CustomerTaskDetailsResponseModel> getCustomerDetails(string customerCode)
        {
            var endPoint = CustomerDetailsEndPoint + "?" + customerCode;
            var result = getToService<List<CustomerTaskDetailsResponseModel>>(endPoint);
            return result;
        }
```

getToService method;

```
private T getToService<T>(string endPoint)

        {

            var clientCertificatePath = ClientCertificatePath;

            var clientCertificatePassword = CertPass;

            var clientCertificate = new X509Certificate2(@clientCertificatePath, clientCertificatePassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);

            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | 

                                                   (SecurityProtocolType)3072 | 

                                                   (SecurityProtocolType)768;

 



            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(endPoint);

            request.ClientCertificates.Add(clientCertificate);

            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", AwsSignature(request, AccessKey, SecretKey));

            request.Headers.Add("x-api-key", ApiKey);

            request.Headers.Add("X-Amz-Date", AmzDate);

 

            request.Method = "GET";

 

            try

            {

                var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))

                {

                    return new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<T>(streamReader.ReadToEnd());

                }

            }

            catch (Exception ex)

            {

                var response = new PMAktifApiBaseResponseModel { ErrorCode = 99, ResponseMsg = string.Format("Error Message: {0} /n Stack Trace: {1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace) };

 

                var serialized = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(response);

 

                var deserialized = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<T>(serialized);

 

                return deserialized;

            }

        }
```

AwsSignature method;

```
private string AwsSignature(HttpWebRequest request, string accessKey, string secretKey)

        {

            string amzDate = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ"); 

            string dateStamp = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyyMMdd");

            AmzDate = amzDate;

            string canonicalUri = "/"; string canonicalQuerystring = "";

            string canonicalHeaders = $"host:{request.Host}\n"; 

            string signedHeaders = "host";

            byte[] payloadHashBytes = new byte[0]; 

            string canonicalRequest = $"{request.Method}\n{canonicalUri}\n{canonicalQuerystring}\n{canonicalHeaders}\n{signedHeaders}\n{HexEncode(payloadHashBytes)}"; 

            string algorithm = "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256";

            string credentialScope = $"{dateStamp}/{Region}/{Service}/aws4_request"; 

            byte[] canonicalRequestHashBytes = Hash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(canonicalRequest)); 

            string canonicalRequestHash = HexEncode(canonicalRequestHashBytes);

            string stringToSign = $"{algorithm}\n{amzDate}\n{credentialScope}\n{canonicalRequestHash}";

            byte[] signingKey = GetSignatureKey(secretKey, dateStamp, Region, Service); 

            byte[] signature = HmacSHA256(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToSign), signingKey); 

            string signatureString = HexEncode(signature); 

            string authorizationHeader = $"{algorithm} Credential={accessKey}/{credentialScope}, SignedHeaders={signedHeaders}, Signature={signatureString}";

 

            return authorizationHeader;

        }
```

Other functions I used;

```
private byte[] GetSignatureKey(string key, string dateStamp, string regionName, string serviceName)

        {

            byte[] kSecret = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"AWS4{key}");

            byte[] kDate = HmacSHA256(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dateStamp), kSecret);

            byte[] kRegion = HmacSHA256(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(regionName), kDate);

            byte[] kService = HmacSHA256(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(serviceName), kRegion);

 

            return HmacSHA256(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("aws4_request"), kService);

        }
```

```
private byte[] HmacSHA256(byte[] data, byte[] key)

        {

            using (HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(key))

            {

                return hmac.ComputeHash(data);

            }

        }
```

```
 private byte[] Hash(byte[] data)

        {

            using (SHA256 sha256 = SHA256.Create())

            {

                return sha256.ComputeHash(data);

            }

        }
```

```
private string HexEncode(byte[] data)

        {

            StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(data.Length * 2);

            foreach (byte b in data)

            {

                hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);

            }

            return hex.ToString();

        }
```

My application's runtime version is dotnet4.0. I can't create request in normal way. I saw this solution even thought its little bit long :). But its getting 403 Forbidden error. Do you know why this problem occurs? Or does anyone has any other options to create AWS api request for dotnet4.0 version?